# Do we have any separate list of css classes used in jquery dialog or any jquery component?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In jquery ui, i am using some components. In jquery ui download page, we are able to deselect unwanted components. But the css file is same for all.

I'd like extract the styles, which i am using from the default jquery ui css file to reduce the size of the file.

Do we have any option for that? Manual extraction is a hard job. Do we have any separate list of styles classes  for each jquery ui component?

Any suggestions would be appreciative!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you download the zip file from JQuery it contains

> - css
> - development-bundle
> - js
> - index.html

Navigate inside

> development-bundle/themes/nameofTheme

The folder will contain all the CSS separately for each component...

You might be using the css file in the css folder in the root of the unzipped directory

Comment: Thanks man. That is what i wanted. I never gone through that dev-bundle.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off loading jQuery UI from a CDN like [Google's](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jqueryUI).

This way you have a good chance it is already cached and won't have to be downloaded.